# 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request. Pivotal Cloud Foundry Dev

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy microgateway as a docker image on Pivotal Cloud Foundry Dev. It is successfully deployed and started but when i hit the url i am getting error as 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

Comment: You have not provided enough info for anyone to be able to answer your question.

Comment: The link of microgateway i am trying to install is https://github.com/CAAPIM/Microgateway .  The environment variable declare into docker-compose I used all these in manifest.yml. I am using only docker-compose.yml and not using consul and lb.dockercloud.